# Robust way to handle app errors inside mapStateToProps?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm looking for advice on the most robust and reliable way to handle errors within mapStateToProps, and if it's even advisable to attempt this at this level within a React+Redux app.

For example, if I use `react-redux`'s `connect` with a component and a `mapStateToProps`:

```
function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
    throw Error('Some unfortunate error.');
    return {
        // some data
    }
}
```

I want to catch this error and maybe display an error component in the place of the rendering component. I will not make any attempt to recover - just pick up and move on.

At the moment I've noticed that this stalls React completely, and the page will probably need to be reloaded: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getHostNode' of null`

Comment: If there is an uncaught exception, the thread will not continue past that point. You don't want to have uncaught exceptions in React components, because as you've discovered it prevents React from properly rendering other components as well.

Comment: @ArneHugo So in essence are you basically saying "if you reach this point in your app and an error is thrown, you need to prevent it from occurring further up the chain"? If so, that's totally understandable and a satisfactory answer IMHO.

Comment: Yeah something like that. Either prevent it from happening in the first place or catch it in an appropriate place (typically you want to catch it before any components fail to render, but sometimes you just render another component instead if the first one fails).

Answer (score 2):

I would handle the exception as regular data since `connect` would still expect some props to pass them to your component. I'd do something like this:

```
function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
 try {
   // code
   return {
       // some data
   }
 } catch (e){
   return {
       error: e
   }
 }
}
```

And then have the component look for `props.error` and display an error message.